# Python3 на CentOS 6, threading - 'can't start new thread', при использовании ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python-3.x, centos

Доброго времени суток, собственно проблема в использовании `ThreadPoolExecutor` из пакета `concurrent.futures`, именно в CentOS 6 при выполнении следующего кода:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()

futures = ()


for i in range(25):
    futures += executor.submit(lambda: print(i)),

wait(futures)
```

Результат таков:

```
1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "thread.py", line 9, in <module>
    futures += executor.submit(lambda: print(i)),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 115, in submit
    self._adjust_thread_count()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 134, in _adjust_thread_count
    t.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 846, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

При этом в данном случае пороговое значение размера пула - 24, такое поведение не проявляется если создавать потоки вручную, то есть через `threading.Thread`, также на других Linux OS тот же `ThreadPoolExecutor` отрабатывает нормально. Очень не вериться что это баг Python именно для CentOS 6. Проверялось на Python-3.5 и 3.6. В чем может быть дело? Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: попробуйте явно `max_workers` параметр указать (посмотрите на [ограничение на кол-во потоков для процесса/системы](http://stackoverflow.com/q/344203/4279)) и `shutdown()` вызвать : `with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    executor.map(print, range(25))` В сторону: подумайте чем `lambda: print(i)` от `print` отличается ([`lambda i=i: print(i)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/139819/4279)).

Comment: ваш код работает на CentOS 6 и Python 3: `docker run --rm -v "$PWD:/prj" nbearson/centos6-python3 python3 /prj/so-user-triplustri.py`

Comment: @jsf - вопрос снимается, были ограничения на уровне виртуальной машины, спасибо. Про `lambda i: print(i)` в цикле - так и знал что кто нибудь обратит внимание)

Comment: этот вопрос может быть полезен и другим людям (для этого сайт и существует). Если можете, оставьте свой ответ (явно причину RuntimeError словами опишите, какой командой предел нашли, как поменяли, то есть как разрешили проблему)—[это явно приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).